# Create bubbles from geojson with Kendo UI

Tags: kendo-ui, geojson

I have a geojson file with a collection of points:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Point one",
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [13,52]
      }
    },...
```

By default those points are displayed as a standard location marker.
[image]

```
$("#map").kendoMap({
            center: [52, 13],
            zoom: 10,
            layers: [{
                type: "shape",
                dataSource: {
                    type: "geojson",
                    transport: {
                        read: function(e) {
                            e.success(myPoints);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }]
        });     
    });
```

But I want to display the points as bubbles. Searching for; how to display geojson data with kendo ui, then I only find tutorials of layer `type: shape` in combination with geojson polygons. If I read the [kendo ui tutorials for type bubble](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/map/configuration/layerdefaults.bubble.style), then there is a value field to define the radius, which is not defined in geojson data. How to edit the standard marker display of geojson points? Or how to setup the properties of a bubble layer with respect to a geojson data input?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to replace the standard location marker with a circle?

Comment: @Shai, yes with the related difference of individual radius for each circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through the [layerDefaults.marker.shape](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/map/configuration/layerdefaults.marker.shape) you can customize the marker and even set a custom icon for the marker, as shown [here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/diagrams-and-maps/map/how-to/custom-markers).

To show bubbles with different size add a [bubble layer](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/map/bubble-layer). Here is a [dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/@AleksandarEvangelatov/eSaWEhOD) with a GeoJSON map and a bubble layer, with the bubble diameter being based on population value.

Edit:
The bubble layer expects data in the following format

```
[
  {
    "City":"City A",
    "Country":"USA",
    "MyValueField":123456789,
    "MyLocationField":[
       45.2,
       24.33
    ]
  },
  {
    "City":"City B",
    "Country":"USA",
    "MyValueField":123456789,
    "MyLocationField":[
     34.47,
     95.28
    ]
  }
]
```

If the endpoint returns the data in a different format you can use the [schema.parse](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/schema#schemaparse) function to parse the response in the expected format:

```
          {
            type: "bubble",
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "https://get/my/data",
                        dataType: "json"
                    }
                },
              schema: {
                parse: function(response) {
                  // parse response to match expected format
                  return response;
                }
              }
            },
            locationField: "MyLocationField", //The Map accepts a [Latitude, Longitude] format for its locations field 
            valueField: "MyValueField"
          }
```

Comment: Thx for the hints. I know those tutorials. Unfortunatly the dataSource type for the bubble layer is not geojson in the tutorial you linked. Why do you think it's geojson format? Only the shape layer is geojson formated.

Comment: Ahh, I see. The bubble layer expects data in a different format. I've updated the answer to demonstrate how you can parse the response.